# convert object to array of objects in this format with my own keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object

```
{TDD_rating: 80, Fluency_rating: 70, Debug_rating: 64, Model_rating: 53, Refactor_rating: 68,}
```

which I want in the format of this array

```
[
  { subject: 'TDD', score: 80 },
  { subject:  'Fluency', score: 70},
  { subject:  'Debug', score: 65},
  { subject:  'Model', score: 53},
  { subject:  'Refactor', score: 68},

];
```

I have tried to use Object.entries and map but can't seem to get there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use combination of `Object.entries()` and `Array.prototype.map()` method to get your result. Get the key value pairs using `Object.entries()` method and then map it to make your required object array.

```js
const data = {
  TDD_rating: 80,
  Fluency_rating: 70,
  Debug_rating: 64,
  Model_rating: 53,
  Refactor_rating: 68,
};

const ret = Object.entries(data).map(([x, y]) => ({
  subject: x.replace('_rating', ''),
  score: y,
}));
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: awesome works perfectly! spent ages wondering how to do it

Comment: Hi sorry to ask again, but I realised I my output I needed is slightly different, I need it without the '_rating' in the subject? How can I do so?

Comment: @JohnnyYip, check it, I have updated the code. Please let me know is it okay now.

Comment: thanks again! Totally new to JS still so finding trouble with these simple things

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to achieve that,

```js
const obj = {
  TDD_rating: 80,
  Fluency_rating: 70,
  Debug_rating: 65,
  Model_rating: 53,
  Refactor_rating: 68,
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => ({ subject: key, score: obj[key] }));
console.log(result);
```